# How to show that the following function is differentiable.

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^n & x \ge 0 \\x^m & x < 0 \end{cases}$$ where $m,n$ are positive integers.Show that the function $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = 0$.

I have defined the function $f_1(x)$ as

$$f_1(x) = \begin{cases} x^{n-1} & x \ge 0 \\x^{m-1} & x < 0 \end{cases}$$

We see that it follows from the definition that $$f(x) = f(0) + f_1(x)x$$

We see that $f_1(0) = 0$ so we need to show that the function $f_1(x)$ is continuous at the point $x = 0$ .We see that the function $f_1(x)$ is a continuous function at $x = 0$ and this can be checked by assuming a sequence $(x_n) \to 0$ then  $f_1(x_n) \to f_1(0)$

Hence we can claim that $f(x)$ is  a differentiable function.

Is my proof correct?Also could someone go through the way I have written it..

Comment: The way that I have tried is it wrong?

Comment: It’s not true if $n=2,m=1.$

Comment: @ThirstForMaths It seems to be true whenever $m = n = 1$ or $m\geq 2$ and $n\geq 2$.